# How can get email about latest vulnerabilities

Tags: email, known-vulnerabilities

Today my friend got email for the latest vulnerablility `heartbleed`.

But i could not find where i can subscribe so that i can also get emails about latest vulnerabilities

Can anyone please help me where should i need to subscribe and which things i need to subscribe for.

Comment: https://secunia.com/ is pretty neat. There are many other services that provide CVE and NVD notifications (Google for that).

Comment: +1 for using email to find out about security issues, rather than finding out via twitter. :( Or I would, if I was registered.

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to the [US-CERT maillist](http://www.us-cert.gov/mailing-lists-and-feeds)
It provides a variety of products. Covers mainly below four topics:

1. Alerts - timely information about current security issues, vulnerabilities, and exploits
2. Bulletins — weekly summaries of new vulnerabilities. Patch information is provided when available
3. Tips - advice about common security issues for the general public
4. Current Activity - up-to-date information about high-impact types of security activity affecting the community at large

Answer (score 1):

Security advisories are normally posted by the project maintainers. In the case of Heartbleed, that would be the OpenSSL team. You should subscribe to the Project Announcements mailing list at https://www.openssl.org/support/community.html.

This OpenSSL mailing list (linked to above) will only address security vulnerabilities (and project releases) specifically for OpenSSL. You should subscribe to other mailing lists for other projects for which you wish to receive notifications (such as Apache, CentOS, RedHat, Ubuntu, pfSense, or what-have-you).

Comment: isn't there any single webiste which mails zero day vulnerability for all major things

Answer (score 0):

exploit-db by offensive security is pretty good. I don't really know of any other places that list exploits or email exploits. They also have a twitter feed that updates when they post new exploits; Their might be others that i'm not aware of.